# android xml button call method of another class

Tags: android, xml, inheritance, button

I have my xml set up so that each class includes the same menu bar. I have to duplicate each method that is called by a button onClick in every class that uses the menu bar though. Is there a way around this? I tried to extend the other class, but every class already extends activity and you cannot extend multiple classes in Android.

Example:
menu bar has button doStuff.
class A includes menu bar. Class A implements doStuff.
class B includes menu bar. Class B implements doStuff.

They are both implementing the same method in exactly the same way. Is there a way to define these methods (like doStuff) once and have each button call that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to make each button call a method. This was repeated in all classes that used buttons. Then these individual methods called a central one, so that the code could be changed from one location, rather then having to repeat changes.

Example: menu bar has button doStuff. class A includes menu bar. Class A implements doStuff. class B includes menu bar. Class B implements doStuff.

Solution: menu bar has button doStuff. class A includes menu bar. Class A implements handler that refers the call to a central class. class B includes menu bar. Class B implements the handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another class which implements `doStuff()` method, and then only set listeners for buttons in every class. You will always have to set listeners, either by calling `setOnClickListener()` (or in XML file, but then I don't know if you can call another classes method). If you need some views from your class, you can then pass them as parameters.